# Expresión regular para procesar una linea de un log de peticiones HTTP

Tags: python, regex

Tengo una sentencia:

```
30.95.91.251 - larson8319 [21/Jun/2019:16:02:02 -0700] "PUT /one-to-one/whiteboard HTTP/1.0" 401 7270
```

la deseo transformar en el siguiente diccionario usando patterns:

```
{"host":"146.204.224.152",
 "user_name":"feest6811",
 "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",
 "request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"}
```

Ya he intentado lo siguiente:

```
pattern="""

(?P<host>.*)    #host id

(-\ )           #slash

(?P<user_name>\w*)  #user_name

([\)            #corchetes

(?P<time>\w*)   #date and time

(] \ )          #corchete

(?P<request>w*) #request"""

for item in re.finditer(pattern,data,re.VERBOSE):

  print(item.groupdict())
```

Sin embargo el output que obtengo es:

```
{'host': '30.95.91.251 ', 'user_name': 'larson831', 'request': ''}
```

No tengo idea como obtener la parte la fecha dentro de los corchetes.

Espero me puedan apoyar

Answer (score 2):

Explico dentro del regex:

```
pattern=r"""

^                                # anclado al inicio de la línea

(?P<host>                        # 1) host id
               \S+               # 1 o más caracteres que no sean espacios en blanco
)                                #

[ ]-[ ]                          # espacio guión espacio (fijate que hay que escapar
                                 # a ambos espacios por estar en verbose)

(?P<user_name>                   # 2) user_name
               \S+               # 1 o más caracteres que no sean espacios en blanco
)  

[ ]                              # 1 espacio

                                 # 3) timestamp
\[                               # `[` literal (va escapado)
(?P<time>                        #
               [^\]]+            # 1 o más caracteres que no sean `]`
)                                #
\]                               # y el `]` de cierre (va escapado)

[ ]                              # 1 espacio

(?P<request>                     # 4) request
      "[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"   # parámetro entre comillas
)
"""
```

- Modificadores: `re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE`